# I m getting this error: you have modified the global:DefaultVIserver and global:DefaultVIServers system variable

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

When I am running the below code, it shows me an error as shown in the screenshot.
And if I remove the `-Parallel` Keyword then it's working fine but I want to execute `net.usage.average` on every host parallelly. Can someone help me out with this problem?
[image: Find error Screenshot]

Comment: Do not post images of code or errors. Post the actual code/error in text.

Answer (score 0):

Passing multiple entities to a single `Get-Stat` call would be a simpler way to get parallelism, IIRC, for example:

```
Get-Stat -Entity (Get-VMHost) -Stat net.usage.average
```

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59272019) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75184580) may help explain the errors with DefaultVIServer(s), maybe moot if passing multiple hosts to `-Entity` gets the parallelism/performance you need without `Foreach-Object -Parallel`.